# Update column in one table based on data in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

**Hvac_Setup**

```
ID (int)
SuiteType (varchar(50))
Suite (varchar(1000))
```

and **Suites**

```
ID (int)
SuiteNumber (varchar(10))
SuiteType (varchar(50))
```

Sample data in the `Hvac_Setup` table:

```
ID | SuiteType (description)  | SuiteNumbers
1  | Helmodul A suite A       | 103A,104A (separated by comma, nn suites)
2  | Helmodul A suite A m/hems| 316A,412A,503A,504A,505B,509A,510A 
3  | Helmodul A suite A m/sov | 217A
```

I wish to write a SQL query that update the `SuiteType` column in the `Suites` table with correct `SuiteType` data from `Hwac_Setup` table where `SuiteNumbers` (in `SuiteNumbers`) match.

Sample data of `Suites` table after update

```
ID |    SuiteNumber | SuiteType
---+----------------+---------------------------    
1  |    103A        | Helmodul A suite A
2  |    104A        | Helmodul A suite A
3  |    316A        | Helmodul A suite A m/hems
..
..
n  |    217A        | Helmodul A suite A m/sov
```

Can someone help me with the syntax?

Comment: You need a string splitter for this. My personal choice is from Jeff Moden and community at sql server central. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ There are a few other excellent choices here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings The biggest issue you have is that your data is not normalized. Storing delimited data violates 1NF and causes incredible amounts of pain.

Comment: what version of sql server. 2016 has a built in function, otherwise you will have to build your own ie the comment above me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
set nocount on 

if object_id ('tempdb..#Hvac_Setup') is not null drop table #Hvac_Setup

create table #Hvac_Setup
    (
    ID int,
    SuiteType varchar(50),
    SuiteNumbers varchar(1000)
    )

if object_id ('tempdb..#Suites') is not null drop table #Suites

create table #Suites
    (
    ID int,
    SuiteNumber varchar(10),
    SuiteType varchar(50)
    )

insert #Hvac_Setup values 
    (1, 'Helmodul A suite A', '103A,104A'),
    (2, 'Helmodul A suite A m/hems', '316A,412A,503A,504A,505B,509A,510A'),
    (3, 'Helmodul A suite A m/sov', '217A')

select * from #Hvac_Setup

insert #Suites values
    (1,'103A', 'Helmodul A suite A'),
    (2,'104A', 'Helmodul A suite A'),
    (3,'316A', 'Helmodul A suite A m/hems')

select * from #Suites

update #Suites 
set SuiteType = hs.SuiteType
from #Suites s
inner join #Hvac_Setup as hs 
on hs.SuiteNumbers like '%'+ s.SuiteNumber +'%'

select * from #Suites
```

Btw: you should try to write your questions in a way that they are consistent (Suite or SuiteNumbers in your table?).